# Insert JSON object data to MySQL using Node.JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I want insert a JSON object into MySQL in Node.js server, this is the code

```
let id = 1
let date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/');
let sql ='INSERT INTO case_record (case_details,gen_date,case_id) VALUES('+caseDetails+','+date+','+id+')'
console.log(sql)
con.query(sql,function(err, result, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    res = result;
    console.log(res)
});
```

This is the caseDetails data

```
let caseDetails = {
    caseData,
    patData, 
    notifData,
    primecData, 
    refData}
```

Each of the object in the caseDetails is JSON object also.
When I excute, the error return is

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object],2019/04/22,1)' at line 1
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: What data type do those fields have? Normally, you should store them as string as mysql don't support an object. Use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to save and [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to load.

Comment: I changed the data type of the case_details field from JSON to long text. I also tried using JSON.stringify() but it still error `ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"caseData":"","patData":"","notifData":"","primecData":"","refData":""},2019-04-' at line 1`

Comment: You also need to wrap them in quotes. `VALUES("'+JSON.stringify(caseDetails)+'", "'+date+'", "'+id+'")`

Comment: This is the sql with quotes wraped`INSERT INTO case_record (case_details,gen_date,case_id) VALUES("{"caseData":"","patData":"","notifData":"","primecData":"","refData":""}", "2019-04-22", "1")` But the error still there

Comment: Solved when I change the statement as@Ali D suggested. Thank you for the suggestion of the JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong to cause parsing error.

Why don't u follow this correction?

```
...
let sql ='INSERT INTO case_record(case_details,gen_date,case_id) VALUES(?,?,?)';
con.query(sql, [caseDetails,date,id] ,function(err, result, fields) {
  ...
});
```

Hope to get helped.