# Insert Statement Node-Red, MySQL, JSON

Tags: mysql, json, insert, node-red

I have the following node-red flow:
[Node-Red Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8RKp.png)

The Problem ist with the insert Statement. I want to insert the measurements in a mysql table, which looks like this:
[MySql Table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQXok.png)

My current insert statement looks like this:

```
var nodeID= parseInt(msg.payload.nodeID);
var temperature= parseFloat(msg.payload.temperature);
var values = {"temperature": temperature};

msg.topic = "INSERT INTO measurements (nodeID,values) VALUES ('"+nodeID+"', '"+JSON.stringify(values)+"')";
msg.payload = [nodeID, temperature];
return msg;
```

which gives me the following error:
"Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values) VALUES ('1', '{"temperature":24.125}')' at line 1"

can someone help me? i cannot figure out what is wrong? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use msg.topic = `INSERT INTO measurements (nodeID,values) VALUES

('${nodeID}','${JSON.stringify(values)}')`;

Comment: thankyou i tried this, but i still got the same error:

"Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values) VALUES ('1','{"temperature":24.125}')' at line 1"

Comment: when i change it to "JSON.parse(values)", the error becoms:"SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1".
any idea?

Comment: Have you tried sending 'values' ​​directly without doing JSON.stringfy?

Comment: Yes i did, then i get this error:"Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values) VALUES ('1', '[object Object]')' at line 1"

Comment: Maybe this solution can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787841/insert-json-object-data-to-mysql-using-node-js)

Comment: i made it now!!!! this is the solution that worked: 
var nodeID= parseInt(msg.payload.nodeID);
var temperature= parseFloat(msg.payload.temperature);
var data = {"temperature": temperature};

msg.topic = "INSERT INTO measurements (nodeID,data) VALUES ('"+nodeID+"','"+JSON.stringify(data)+"')";
//msg.topic = `INSERT INTO measurements (nodeID,values) VALUES ('${nodeID}','${JSON.stringify(results)}')`;
msg.payload = [nodeID, temperature];
return msg;

so i think it was either the keyword "values" that i missused or the JSON.stringify.. aniway, thank for the help :)

Comment: I added a down vote because the recommended way to use BVs

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to use *bind values*:

```js
const { payload } = msg;
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO measurements (nodeID,values) VALUES (?, ?);";
msg.payload = [
    payload.nodeID, 
    JSON.stringify({ temperature: Number(payload.temperature) }),
];
return msg;
```

The node will handle the needed JS to MySQL type conversions, though I am not sure why you would want to use a `JSON` field type to store a single key:value pair.